# How do I add and retrieve items that have a certain value without using a scan function ? DynamoDb

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I need to search a DB which is similar to this one.

[image]
[image]

What options do I have to get the userids of all the people in the DB if it had 1Milllion such entries.

I have heard that a `table.scan(FilterExpression=Attr('time').eq("now")).` can be very expensive when I have a huge DB.

Is there a way where I can do something like a find all userids with the time "now" without reading(scaning) the whole DB.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Add secondary indexes to your table.

In your specific example you might create a "Local" secondary index with "userid" as it's partition key and add "time" as the sort key.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the global secondary index (GSI) with hash key as `time` attribute and `userid` as partition key. You can use `Query API` and get the data for the `time` attribute without scanning all the items in the table.

Please note that `LSI` (Local Secondary Index) may not work as hash key is must to use Query API. LSI is used when you need alternate sort key for the table.